# Replacing ID's from SQL query with certain name from another table. But my both tables have multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables (there will be more of them): "providers" and "locations"

`PROVIDERS` table:

```
| provider_id | provider_name | departure_id | destination_id |
| ----------- | ------------- | ------------ | -------------- |
|      1      |     DEVO      |      1       |       2        |
|      2      |     PEPO      |      2       |       1        |
```

`LOCATIONS` table

```
                                 (not needed)      (not needed)
| location_id | location_name |location_address |  location_geo  |
| ----------- | ------------- | --------------- | -------------- |
|      1      |     Paris     |   address_111   |     2222       |
|      2      |     London    |   address_222   |     3333       |
```

I'm using Python and getting data from the DB. I need all row from the `PROVIDERS`, but awaiting such result using SQL

```
[ (1, 'DEVO', 'Paris', 'London'), (2, 'PEPO', 'London', 'Paris') ]
```

What request do I need to use, to `SELECT` data from `PROVIDERS` and change ids with names?

Thank you.

I've tried `INNER JOIN`'s, `JOIN`'s and others, but I'm sure that I made a stupid mistake, and I don't understand what it is... I'm getting empty list or list where ids doesn't change

Expecting:

```
[ (1, 'DEVO', 'Paris', 'London'), (2, 'PEPO', 'London', 'Paris') ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can JOIN to the same table more than once and distinguish between them via table aliases. You should also never just `SELECT *` for production queries; always specify the exact column names:

```
SELECT p.provider_id, p.provider_name
   ,ls.location_name as departure_name, ld.location_name as destination_name
FROM Providers p
INNER JOIN Locations ls ON ls.location_id = p.departure_id
INNER JOIN Locations ld ON ld.location_id = p.destination_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to join your PROVIDERS table twice with the LOCATIONS table. Once for Departure Location and second for Destination Location.

Something like below:

```
SELECT p.provider_id, p.provider_name, ldep.location_name departure_location, ldest.location_name destination_location
FROM PROVIDERS  p
INNER JOIN LOCATIONS  ldep on p.departure_id = ldep.location_id
INNER JOIN LOCATIONS  ldest on p.destination_id = ldest.location_id
```